# SQL Server query success but no results

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server Management Studo v 18.12.1 on a VDI with 64bit Windows Microsoft SQL Server 2019.  This device has 96 GB of free space and also has free temporary space.
I loaded a new database and table which has 1,301,902 rows from a csv with no errors using the Data import tool. I have used this on several other tables in this server with no problem.
I run a query like this

```
set rowcount 10
select xyz.["PPI"],xyz.["Business Mailing Address One"]
from [DBNAME].[dbo].[table_name] xyz
```

and this returns:

```
"PPI"   "Business Mailing Address One"
"7251"  "2100 S TRAVIS DR"  
"1346"  "392 HAWKINS ST"    
"1351"  "PO BOX 81001-0798" 
"0289"  "123 E MAIN ST"     
"4022"  "2890 KLAMATH FALLS BLVD"   
"19118" "3639 E FALLS DR"   
"8421"  ""  ""  
"45800" ""  ""  
"6507"  ""  ""  
"1112"  ""  ""
```

Then run this query

```
set rowcount 0
select xyz.["PPI"],xyz.["Business Mailing Address One"]
from [DBNAME].[dbo].[table_name] xyz
where xyz.["Business Mailing Address One"] like 'PO%'
```

This returns:

```
"PPI"   "Business Mailing Address One"
```

zero rows... Query executed successfully

Using = 'PO%' has the same result
Also copied the response into the where statement like
where xyz.["Business Mailing Address One"] = 'PO BOX 81001-0798'
and also get the same result

Comment: Side note, those are some truly terrible object names. I really suggest fixing them.

Comment: Should it not be `LIKE '"PO%'`? You've quoted **everything** in double quotes, your object names *and* the values in the columns. Considering that you do that consistently for the objects (in the result set and the SQL), this suggests that value isn't `'PO BOX 81001-0798'` it's `'"PO BOX 81001-0798"'`; seems you have some significant data and design issues.

Comment: @Simeon That statement is wrong. From [SET ROWCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): *"To set this option off so that all rows are returned, specify SET ROWCOUNT 0."*

Comment: Most likely the problem here is that you are importing data from your CSV and *not* defined your quote identifier when doing so; this is why all your objects/values have double quotes (`"`) around them. Very likely you would be better off `DROP`ing your table(s) and reimporting them and ensuring you **properly define** your quote operator and data types as, at least for this table, you would have defined *all* the columns as an `(n)varchar`. `PPI`, for example, appears like it should be an `int` value, *not* an `(n)varchar` value.

Comment: The query also fails with '"PO%"'.  It is not clear from response whether you think dropping the table, renaming the columns and removing the "'s will fix the problem or would just be a better table.  PPI may look like an int base on 10 values but works better as a varchar and allows matching to other tables.  I retried by pasting the exact value like xyz.["Business Mailing Address One"] = '"PO BOX 81001-0798"' and this returned rows.  I am not sure whether to accept since it doesn't work as a wildcard and will check that too.

Comment: So are you saying your values should all have double quotes around them? *Why*?

Comment: I did retest and a wildcard % is not working in other queries where the column names don't have a double quote.  For that reason, I would like to accept Larnu's answer and will do so when I can find instructions that work.  In the meantime, I've upvoted it.

Comment: @Larnu,  because the column name includes the double quotes,  or alternately because this "works" in that it returns data.   I had tried double and single quotes but not all variations.  Your answer suggested a solution which works.  Yes, I could create a better table and do a bunch of work to remove double quotes but just in case I or someone needs to work with a table like this,  that answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your data exactly how it is, and assuming that all values appear in the dataset are surrounded with quotes, you would need to ensure your fuzzy search also starts with a quote.
[image: Fuzzy Search with quotes]

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE(
["PPI"] VARCHAR(10),
["Business Mailing Address One"] NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
('"7251"',  '"2100 S TRAVIS DR"') , 
('"1346"',  '"392 HAWKINS ST"'),    
('"1351"',  '"PO BOX 81001-0798"'), 
('"0289"',  '"123 E MAIN ST"'),     
('"4022"',  '"2890 KLAMATH FALLS BLVD"'),
('"19118"', '"3639 E FALLS DR"'),   
('"8421"',  '"  "'),  
('"45800"', '"  "'),  
('"6507"',  '"  "'), 
('"1112"',  '"  "') 


SELECT xyz.["PPI"], xyz.["Business Mailing Address One"] 
FROM @Data xyz
WHERE xyz.["Business Mailing Address One"] like '"PO%'
```

Comment: Thanks @swolfe2  I can confirm this worked with like '"PO%' or with like '"PO%"'.  Yet two days ago the '"PO"' was not working.  Perhaps I made a typo somewhere, but today I've tried both variants and get the same results.  Recognize this is not a great table set up but intended to get something done fast and not meant for long term usage.